# Is there a way to implement Two-Phase Locking in Rust? It's almost impossible to implement the growing phase

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust, mutex

C++ Implementation:

```
//growing phase
    for (int index : sorted_transaction) {
      Row &row = table[index];
      row.lock.lock();
    }
//critical section
    for (int index : random_transaction) {
      Row &row = table[index];
      int row_data = row.getData();
      row_data += 1;
      row.setData(row_data);
    }
//shrinking phase
    for (int index : sorted_transaction) {
      Row &row = table[index];
      row.lock.unlock();
    }
```

Rust Attempt

```
        let mut acquired_locks: Vec<&MutexGuard<i32>> = Vec::new();
//        sort phase
        sorted_readset.rdxsort();

//      growing phase
        for index in sorted_readset {
            let u_index = index  as usize;
            let row = &table[u_index];
            let guard = row.lock.lock().unwrap();
            acquired_locks.push(&guard);
        }
//critical section
        for index in random_readset {
            let u_index = index as usize;
            let mut row = &mut table[u_index];
            row.value = row.value + 1;
        }

//since this will become out of scope, it'll automatically shrink
```

As you can see, it's impossible since the Mutex is immediately released after exiting the loop, once ownership is released. I attempted to transfer ownership by appending it to a vector. That throws an error since the lockguard is a borrowed value.

Comment: "I attempted to transfer ownership by appending it to a vector" - but you're appending references to the vector as opposed to letting the vector own the guard a la `Vec<MutexGuard<i32>>`... In your situation the vector is borrowing the guard that is owned by the inside of the first loop.

Comment: What is the `i32` that the `Mutex`es are guarding? C++ mutexes don't wrap their values like Rust mutexes do so I'm trying to figure out what the correlation is between the two pieces of code. Two functions, one in C++ and one in Rust, where the C++ one compiles and the Rust one has a borrowing error, would be a sufficient [mre] (be sure to include all the types, traits, etc. that the code needs to compile -- the borrowing issue should be the only one as far as you can tell.)

Comment: Actually, I was using dummy values just to separate the lock and the value that's being updated(wanted to stick to something similar to my C++ implementation).

Yeah, actually fixed that problem. Storing the vectors by value. However, I'm experiencing a different problem now. Row needs to be mutable since I'm only gonna update it on the second loop(critical section). However, I can't have a mutable borrow...
```
let mut row = &mut table[u_index];
^^^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
```